# Can not add table name ,it shows error message :『Object required 』(VBA)

Tags: vba

```
Sub FilterRows(Field As String, Values As Collection)
  Dim FinalRow As Long
  Dim CellValue As Variant
  Dim Table As ListObject
  Dim i As Integer

  With Worksheets("原始資料")
    FinalRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
     
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
       Set Table = .ListObjects("Table1")
    ErrorHandler:
       Set Table = .ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, .Range("A1:AK" & FinalRow), , xlYes).Name = _
      "Table1"
    Resume Next
    
    For Each CellValue In Values
        For Each Row In Table.ListRows
            Debug.Print Intersect(Row.Range, Table.ListColumns(Field).Range).Value
        Next Row
    Next CellValue
 End With
End Sub
```

I got an error message :『Object required 』at the statement『Set Table = .ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, .Range("A1:AK" & FinalRow), , xlYes).Name = _"Table1"』.

really dont know why...Any Suggestion ? Thanks!

Comment: Error handlers should be separated from normal code flow. Here the code inside the error handler is always executed, so the line `Set Table = .ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRa...` is executed even if no error occurred in the previous line. The next row `Resume Next` will fail since there is nothing to resume from.

Comment: Since the `On error ... `is still active, you will then enter the error handler routine, and execute the `Set Table = .ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRa...` again, but since the context is different it will raise the error you see and since the you are already inside the handler the new error won't be handled and pop up the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's best to separate the error handling code from the main code. See my comments.

You can try the following code (it should work, but I haven't fully tested it):

```
Sub FilterRows(Field As String, Values As Collection)
    Dim FinalRow As Long
    Dim CellValue As Variant
    Dim Table As ListObject
    Dim i As Integer

    With Worksheets("原始資料")
        FinalRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
        Set Table = .ListObjects("Table1")

        For Each CellValue In Values
            For Each Row In Table.ListRows
                Debug.Print Intersect(Row.Range, Table.ListColumns(Field).Range).Value
            Next Row
        Next CellValue
    End With
    Exit sub
ErrorHandler:
    If Table Is Nothing Then
        'If the error is "Table1" not existing
        Set Table = Worksheets("原始資料").ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Worksheets("原始資料").Range("A1:AK" & FinalRow), , xlYes)
        Table.Name = "Table1"
        Resume Next
    Else
        'If it is an other Error
        'Do something?
    End if
End Sub
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, After I modified my code as you said,I still got a same error Message『Object required 』at the statement『Set Table = .ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, .Range("A1:AK" & FinalRow), , xlYes).Name = _"Table1"』

Comment: Did you notice the statement I put contains the Worksheet? `Set Table = Worksheets("原始資料").ListObjects...`?

Comment: Yep I noticed that, I have added in my statement and executed but still got error. The reason why it doesnt show in my comment because I just copyed my previous post text so...my mistake

Comment: Ok, you need the `Worksheets("原始資料")` before the `.Range(...` too  (edited my answer). If it's still not working, it means there is no `Worksheets("原始資料")`

Comment: Ok, also you cannot set the Table and the Name in the same instruction, you need to do this on two lines

Comment: Yep I also have added Worksheets("原始資料") before the .Range(.., Sorry I forgot to tell you that, And I pretty sure I have Worksheets("原始資料") in my workbook. I want to show you at the beginning but I don't know how to add screenshot image in my comment. Is there any way I can show you my code and workbook?

Comment: See my last edit and comment about the Naming of the table needing to be a second instruction

Comment: It works ! After I sperate my instruction, Thanks !